# SwiftUI switching TextField on tab not working with ScrollView

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am experiencing a bug when using TextField in a ScrollView in SwiftUI for macOS.

I am having many different `TextField`, in Stacks arranged. When I select the first one and press tab on the keyboard, the focus automatically jumps to the next one. It works fine.

The actual problem is, that this is not working when the next `TextField` is inside a `ScrollView`. If I manually select the first `TextField` *inside* the `ScrollView`, then Tab is working fine. Eventhough back jumping with `Shift+Tab` out of the `ScrollView` work.

Any workaround for that? Why does SwiftUI does not recognize the next `TextField` inside a `ScrollView`. It is not a smooth experience, always having to manually click into the TextField, when Tab was working before. I created a demo to show the issue:

```
struct ScrollViewBug: View {
    
    @State var s_string : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Group
        {
            VStack()
            {
                TextField("First", text: self.$s_string)
            }
            VStack()
            {
                TextField("Second ", text: self.$s_string)
            }
            
            ScrollView()
            {
                TextField("Third", text: self.$s_string)
                TextField("Fourth ", text: self.$s_string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issues with ScrollView. I've reported a Feedback to Apple (FB8652415), you can report another one with my number and they will hear us quickly.

Comment: @AlbertUI Will do, thanks :)